# Macro definition not included while linking

Tags: c++, c, gcc, linker

I am using following code inside my .c file and then I am creating library file for same.

```
#define abc void printa()\ 
{\
  printf("a");\
}
```

In some other file I used above `abc` function. But when I am Linking both files it is not printing a.

Is there some thing tha if I use in Macro definition, it will not be included in library file  (.a file).

Comment: The 'function' is a macro `abc`, but you mention an `add` function.  Note that the function `printa()` will not be created until you write `abc` outside the scope of a function, somewhere. You can, of course, use it -- though you'd need to declare it before you use it.  (The macro is not a function declaration.)  Note that the `a` won't be printed until you call the function, and arrange for the output to be flushed (e.g. by using `printf("a\n");` in the body of the function defined in the macro.

Comment: Linking is done far later than precprocessing.

Comment: The preprocessor adjust input text (macros) of input files, the changed input is passed to the compiler and the outputs of the compiler are passed to the linker. Hence no macro is 'linked' (The tool chain preprocessor/compiler/linker might be a simplification)

Comment: If you want it as a library function is would make more sense to define the (short) macro function in a library header file as an inline function.

Answer (score 3):

The macro definition `abc`

```
#define abc void printa()\ 
{\
  printf("a");\
}
```

Can't be seen from the linker. The CPP preprocessor just replaces any occurrence of `abc` with

```
void printa() 
{
   printf("a");
}
```

If you want to have functions visible to the linker give them a declaration and defintion like

```
void abc() {
   printf("a");
}
```